# c++ math assignment

Tags: c++, math

The assignment is to write a computer program that will add 1/3 to itself a large number of times and to compare the result to multiplying 1/3 by the number of times 1/3 was added to itself. It is also to do the same thing with ½.The program is to do this arithmetic twice, once using single precision (float) and once using double precision (double). Both of these will be in one program. Make certain you use a type for your counter that works with these large numbers.
Your program will do these additions 109 (1 billion) times.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;
typedef std::numeric_limits< double > dbl;
int main()
{
    long size=1000000000;
    int count=0;
    long N=10;
    float nAdd=1;
    float nMul=1;

    cout.precision(dbl::digits10);
    cout<<"Iterration #\t\tAdd\t\t\tMul"<<endl;
    for(long  i=1; i<=size; i++)
    {
        nAdd+=1.0/3.0;
        nMul*=1.0/3.0;


        count++;
        if(count%N==0 && count!=0)
        {
            N*=10;
            cout<<i<<"\t\t"<<fixed <<nAdd<<"\t\t"<<fixed <<nMul<<endl;
        }
        if(count==size)
        {
            cout<<"Difference : "<<fixed <<nAdd<<" - "<<fixed <<nMul<<" = "<<fixed <<nAdd-nMul<<endl;
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

so for i have done this
i don't get it properly
what number i have to use which will be multiply by 1/3 or 1/3 will be added into it

can you guyz explain me this a lil
thanks alot

Comment: Are you having trouble with the "add 1/3 to itself a large number of times" part?

Comment: This is an assignment homework. Should not be asked in this community.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but right now your code multiplies the initial value 1000000000 times by 1/3. That is not what the assignment said.

Comment: Please try to trim this question down, and make it generic enough that you either realize where the fault was, or can actually get help from the community and provide content that will help someone else.

Comment: actually i didn't understand "add 1/3 to itself a large number of times"
does this means start from number 1 and then in each iteration add 1/3 in it means 1 then 1.33 then 1.66 and so on???

and same with multiplication?

Comment: @Arpit sir i am not asking code
em just confused in this question.. i will code by myself just need someone to explain it a little bit more

Comment: @jogojapan sir thats what i understood from assignment.. can you clarify what i am doing wrong just give me direction what i should do

Comment: There are two distinct operations you need to perform: (a) Add 1/3 a large number of times to itself (you are doing this already, except that your initial value is 1 instead of 1/3). (b) Multiply 1/3 by the number of times you added it to itself in (a). Note that (b) does not require a loop. It's just one multiplication. Finally, you compare the results of (a) and (b), and -- I guess -- print the result of the comparison. You also need to do all this with 1/2 instead of 1/3, and double instead of float. That's all.

Comment: @jogojapan thanks alot for your help
still confused in (b) how it is a single multiplication? coz i think i have to multiply number with 1/3 to same number of times...

sorry for bothering again

Comment: No. It says _multiplying 1/3 by the number of times 1/3 was added to itself_. And this makes sense of course, because multiplying M x N is supposed to be the same as adding M to itself N times. (The output of your program will reveal if it really ends up being the exact same when binary floating point arithmetic is used.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> add 1/3 to itself a large number of times

This means that you should add ⅓ a bunch of times: ⅓ + ⅓ + ⅓ + ⅓ + ...

Then you're supposed to compare the result of that calculation with the result of multiplying ⅓ by the number of times you added it. So for example if you add it together four times (⅓ + ⅓ + ⅓ + ⅓) then you compare that result with the result of ⅓ × 4.

Mathematically the results should be the same, but the purpose of this assignment is to teach you something about how the computer performs the calculation.