# float value issue

Tags: c++

I am facing problem using float

in loop its value stuck at 8388608.00

```
int count=0;
    long X=10;
    cout.precision(flt::digits10);
    cout<<"Iterration #"<<setw(15)<<"Add"<<setw(21)<<"Mult"<<endl;
    float Start=0.0;
    float Multiplication = Addition * N;
    long i = 1;
    for (i; i <= N; i++){
        float temp = Start + Addition;
        Start=temp;
        count++;
        if(count%X==0 && count!=0)
        {
            X*=10;
            cout<<i;
            cout<<fixed<<setw(30)<<Start<<setw(20)<<fixed<<i*Addition<<endl;
        }
    }
```

what should i do??

Comment: What is `Addition` defined as?  Why are you using float rather than double?

Comment: its an assignment i have to use double and float
Addition is float type variable passed in this method

Comment: Please try to provide a [Short self contained correct example](http://sscce.org/). For instance, what is `N` here?

Comment: sorry about that i should have mentioned these things
code was not readable here so i pasted on this site

http://paste2.org/p/2338466

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Floating point addition](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BinMath/addFloat.html) doesn't work when you're adding (relatively) small number to (relatively) big one. It's caused by the way [float is stored in memory](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/digital_arithmetic/files/ch8.pdf).

You may try replacing [single precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (`float`) with [double precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (`double`) representation but if that doesn't work you'll probably need to implement hack like this:

```
// Lets say
double OriginalAddition = 0.123;
int Addition = 1;

// You just use base math substitution:
// Addition = OriginalAddition
int temp = Start + Addition;  // You will treat transform floating point to fixed point
                              // with step 0.123, so 1 = 0.123
// And when displaying result (transform back into original floating point):
printf( "%f", (double)result*OriginalAddition)
```

This needs a lot of thought to find a substitution that doesn't cause data loss, covers required precision and won't cause `int` to overflow. Try to google [*fixed point int C*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=fixed%20point%20c%20int) (some results: [1](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Binary_Integer_Fixed_Point_Numbers.html), [2](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/other/4024639/Fixed-point-math-in-C)) to get better idea what to do.

Comment: whats purpose of int Addition??

Comment: @MudasarEllahi it's your floating point number transformed into fixed point representation. See additional links.

Comment: em doing this assignment
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890289/c-math-assignment

and i can't start Addition from 1 it is 1/3 so it rounds to 0 :(

Comment: @MudasarEllahi the point is to substitute 1/3 with "x" (in my example 1) and when you're printing out replace it back. That hides error in iteration and when printing you may get the same value twice, but int will keep iterating.